# How do I stop my navbar from deforming when resizing browser window

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, resize, navbar

I have a problem with my website, I want it to stay the same width and height no matter the window size, i managed to do it with pretty much the whole body but the navbar.
[image: FULL SIZE]

[image: SMALL SIZE]

My code for the resizing to stop looks like this so far:

```
<div style="min-width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;">
```

I am using bootstrap 3, classes for my navbar:

```
<nav  id="navbar1" class="jumbotron navbar navbar-default ">
```

Sorry if I am asking something obvious, but I've been learning web dev for a month or so.
EDIT: my navbar code

```
  <nav  id="navbar1" class="jumbotron navbar navbar-default ">
  <div class="container-fluid col-lg-12 col-sm-12 boxy col-xs-12">
    <div class="navbar-header">


      <a id="znacka" class="navbar-brand" href="#"><strong> PIZZA NICK'S</strong> </a>
    </div>

    <div>
      <ul  class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li id="polozka_navbar" ><a href="#">Pizza</a></li>
        <li id="polozka_navbar"><a href="#">Cestoviny</a></li>
        <li id="polozka_navbar"><a href="#">Galéria</a></li>
      </ul>

      <form  align = 'right'>
      <button  id="facebook" class="btn btn-primary" onclick=" window.open('https://www.facebook.com/pizzanickstopolcany/','_blank')">Facebook</button>
      </form>
        <div align = 'right' id="cisla">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <p> Volajte hneď teraz! <br>0917 711 216 || 0948 218 886 </p>
            </thead>
          </table>

        </div>
 </nav>
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you sure you put the div around the navbar? It looks like the div is only used for the main content, and that the body is still 100% wide. But anyway, any solution would be nothing more than guesswork. We need a piece of code that demonstrates the issue reliably. A [mcve].

Comment: Why in the world would you put `.jumbotron` on a navbar?

Comment: didn't know how to make the navbar big enough without it